# Relay.js Error: repeat() argument must be greater than or equal to 0 and not be infinity

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. My relay query seems to be composed correctly (i.e. i can verify query is successfully returning results expected) but I'm getting the error of `Error: repeat() argument must be greater than or equal to 0 and not be infinity` when the app renders in the browser.

The app has been fine until I added the fragment for paginated results (`edge` + `node`):

```
const ConversationContainer = Relay.createContainer(Conversation, {
  fragments: {
    conversation: () => Relay.QL`fragment on Conversation {
      id
      fingerprint
      unreadCount
      messages(first: 3) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
        }
        edges {
          node {
            body
          },
          cursor
        },
      }
    }`
  }
})
```

and the presentation component:

```
class Conversation extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, fingerprint, unreadCount, messages } = this.props.conversation;
    return <div>
      <div>conversation <code>{id}</code></div>
      <div>fingerprint: <code>{fingerprint}</code>, unreadCount: {unreadCount}</div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(messages, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

So what's the cause of the error?

Edit: the error is in the UI as rendered by my root component's `renderFailure` property (also as warning in the console)

```
const root = <Relay.RootContainer
  Component={AppContainer}
  route={new AppRoute()}
  renderLoading={() => <div>Loading...</div>}
  renderFailure={(error, retry) => <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
/>;
```

Comment: Relay fragment looks good to me. The problem may be related to string: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/commit/0f8e08326475e10e9f358394d2da3ada8f5ce8d1
May be printing elements of `messages` one by one will reveal something.

Answer (score 3):

Two things I can think of:

#### RelayNetworkLayer

This might be related to your GraphQL server and not Relay.

Take a look at this line from the Relay source:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/a1a4d99cb698e1eed63d28f8291ef114115d515d/src/network-layer/default/RelayDefaultNetworkLayer.js#L193

I know this is really weird but would your server be returning errors with negative column values by any chance ?

#### getBabelRelayPlugin

https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/00de34d32d51ba9e4d17e45280ad6d7e2734c6ed/scripts/babel-relay-plugin/src/getBabelRelayPlugin.js#L155

Again related to errors, but this time client side schema validation. Although you seem to say your query runs fine, that would imply your schema is valid.

Can you show us what the GraphQL server is returning ?

Comment: good call looking at errors in the payload. I am seeing errors in the returned payload `"Field 'id': No source non-global ID value could be fetched from the source object"` but no negative offsets (all offset `0`)

Comment: @craigb I believe this is a bug in Relay, your column is probably 0 and offset is calculated as `column - 1`, which breaks `repeat`.

I opened a PR here: https://github.com/facebook/relay/pull/1105